# Zabbix: Monitor devices behind host

Tags: zabbix

I have a linux server with avreg set up and several cameras attached to it. The server has WAN ip address and the other nic is attached to switch with some IP-cameras attached to the switch.

Zabbix server is set up to monitor only the server with avreg, and cannot gain access to cameras.

The goal is to monitor cameras by simply pinging it from the avreg server and pass this info to zabbix.

I tried to make custom parameters for zabbix like this one

```
UserParameter=campstate, /bin/ping -c 1 10.4.4.196 | grep packets | awk -F',' '{print $3}' | awk -F' ' '{print $1}' | awk -F'%' '{print $1}'
```

This returns 0 when camera is online and 100 - when it's down.

But zabbix says that it is not supported.

How can i make the desired checks?

Comment: Seems to work for me. Does Zabbix user have the permissions to execute /bin/ping and send ICMP packets? Maybe SELinux is preventing it? Does "zabbix_agentd -t campstate" work as root and as Zabbix user?

Comment: I did this task the other way - ping -c 2 10.4.4.196 > /dev/null; echo $? and this returns "0" when host is alive and "1" when host is down. When i try to test with zabbix - it works fine when host is alive, and reports ZBX_NOTSUPPORTED - Timeout while executing a shell script in case if host is down. So the problem seems to be with the fact that zabbix don't get data in a desired period of time and reports a timeout and error.

Comment: The fact that the item becomes not supported is not good. How about using the timeout option of "ping" (e.g., "ping -c 2 10.4.4.196 -W 1")?